# Python: How do i adjust a value in a XML file?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Student keenly studying python here. i have a task in which i am required to subtract a value within a XML file but cannot find a way to do it. i've been searching for a while and have came up with code that gets close, but never what i need (examples below). the XML file is below as well as a few blocks of code i have attempted to solve the problem with

XML File:

```
<departments>
<department>
    <name>Accounts</name>
    <balance>295.00</balance>
</department>
<department>
    <name>English</name>
    <balance>595.00</balance>
</department>
<department>
    <name>Mathematics</name>
    <balance>26.00</balance>
</department>
```

my task is to subtract a value from a certain department by using ElementTree. i have attempted this with the help of tutorials and code online but to no avail. i.e:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('departments.xml') 
root = tree.getroot()
print(root)
for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
total = 150
ss = 1
while ss != 0:
    cu = input("Which Department (English, Mathematics, Accounts)" )
    if cu in ["English", "e", "E", "Eng", "eng"]: 
        for balance in (root[1]):
            balance = int(float((balance.text)))+10
            tree.write('output.xml')
            ss -= 1
    elif cu in ["Math", "math", "M", "m", "Mathematics", "mathematics"]:
        pc = "m"
        ss -= 1
    elif cu in ["accounts", "A", "a", "Accounts", "account", "Account"]:
        pc = "a"
        ss -= 1
    else:
        print("Error, type English, Mathematics, or Accounts")
```

the output is as follows:

```
<Element 'departments' at 0x0000021DF0E128B0>
department {}
department {}
department {}
Which Department (English, Mathematics, Accounts)e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Vadder\Desktop\py\2021\Software\Teams_tasks\SAC\Code\V.1.1\dept_2.py", line 14, in <module>
    balance = int(balance.text)+10
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'English'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

this is part of the code i attempted in which the user would select that the total was going to be subtracted from the English department, but i cannot seem to find the right way to select the **value of 'balance'**. i have managed to select everything but, with the help of '.tag' and '.text'. any help would be valued
thanks, Vadder

note: also, any tips on what to include or anything to make my question more concise when posting here would be greatly appreciated. thanks :)

EDIT: the code that ended up working was below,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\Vadder\Desktop\py\2021\Software\Teams_tasks\SAC\Code\V.1.1\departments.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
total = 150.0
ss = 1
while ss != 0:
     cu = input("Which Department (English, Mathematics, Accounts)" )
     if cu in ["English", "e", "E", "Eng", "eng"]:
        element = root[1].find('balance')
        if int(float(element.text)) >= total: 
            element.text = str(int(float((element.text)))-total)
            tree.write('output.xml')
        else:
            print("sorry, your department does not have the sufficent funds")        
        ss -= 1
     elif cu in ["Math", "math", "M", "m", "Mathematics", "mathematics"]:
        element = root[2].find('balance')
        if int(float(element.text)) >= total: 
            element.text = str(int(float((element.text)))-total)
            tree.write('output.xml')
        else:
            print("sorry, your department does not have the sufficent funds")        
        ss -= 1
     elif cu in ["accounts", "A", "a", "Accounts", "account", "Account"]:
        element = root[0].find('balance')
        if int(float(element.text)) >= total: 
            element.text = str(int(float((element.text)))-total)
            tree.write('output.xml')
        else:
            print("sorry, your department does not have the sufficent funds")        
        ss -= 1
     else:
        print("Error, type English, Mathematics, or Accounts")
```

its a very rigid and repetitive structure, and it means i cannot change the department order within the XML file, but it works, and i don't have time to make it more adaptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert at Python by any means but from what I could tell you we're going too far down into the xml element.

So

```
    if cu in ["English", "e", "E", "Eng", "eng"]: 
    for balance in (root[1]):
        balance = float((balance.text))+10
        tree.write('output.xml')
        ss -= 1
```

becomes

```
if cu in ["English", "e", "E", "Eng", "eng"]:
    element = root[0].find('balance')
    element.text = str(float((element.text)+10))
    tree.write('output.xml')
    ss -= 1
```

Assuming you know the absolute index of the department you want to update. Also, assuming you want to keep the same level of accuracy, you don't need to make it a float and then an int, you can just use a float.

The full code I used for testing it, which isn't much differnt from yours just used `ET.dump` to output the XML to make it more useful in debugging.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('departments.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print(root)
for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
total = 150
ss = 1
while ss != 0:
   cu = input("Which Department (English, Mathematics, Accounts)" )
   if cu in ["English", "e", "E", "Eng", "eng"]:
        element = root[0].find('balance')
        element.text = str(int(float((element.text)))+10)
        tree.write('output.xml')
        ss -= 1
        ET.dump(tree)
    elif cu in ["Math", "math", "M", "m", "Mathematics", "mathematics"]:
        pc = "m"
        ss -= 1
    elif cu in ["accounts", "A", "a", "Accounts", "account", "Account"]:
        pc = "a"
        ss -= 1
    else:
        print("Error, type English, Mathematics, or Accounts")
```

Comment: Hi! with your help, i seemed to make it work very reliably. the code i ended up with is in the edit above. thanks heaps!!